# HTML. Заменить inline base64 картинки в <img> внешними файлами

Tags: html, python, shell, base64, sed

Есть файл с html. На самом деле это вообще дамп базы mysql.
В нем есть вставленные инлайном картинки. Это неправильно.
Есть замечательная команда
`sed -e 's/<img[^<]*base64[^<]*\/>//g' infile`
Она убирает эти картинки. До недавнего времени меня это устраивало.
Но теперь эти картинки нужно выгрузить на диск, развернуть из base64 в изображения и вставить назад уже ссылкой на эти изображения.

Что подскажете? Как это сделать?
Есть shell, python, perl...

Comment: голосую за закрытие данного вопроса - он слишком обширный для SO.

Comment: Какой именно шаг вызывает у вас затруднения?  Как найти inline картинки в html? Как данные прочитать data: URL? Как эти данные на диск сохранить? Как заменить значения атрибутов у картинок?

Comment: Я уже пишу на питоне. Надеялся, что кто-то уже сталкивался и есть готовое решение. Закрывайте, наверное.

Comment: Python + ElementTree.

Answer (score 0):

Я написал на Питоне программку, делающую следующее:
Она берет распакованную базу SQL и ищет в ней все включения "base64".
Если она находит их, то вытаскивает содержимое и декодирует его во внешние файлы. И в src= прописывает ссылки на эти файлы.
Не все красиво, но оно работает.
Даже не заморачивался имя файла параметром передавать. Все сделал bash-обвязкой.
Тем более, что у меня пакетник делает эту процедуру для многих сайтов.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import re
import lxml.html as LH
import uuid

filein = 'base.sql'                   # имя файла источника
filout = 'base-opt.sql'               # имя файла исправленной базы
imgdir = "sites/default/files/images" # сюда складываем файлы картинок

def find_between( s, first, last ): # Функция возвращает строку между заданными сигнатурами. Можно просто регуляркой заменить.
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

def save_to_file(source):   # Функция берет строку, достает из нее base64, распаковывает и записывает в файл
    ext = ".jpg"            # разбираемся какой формат файла закодирован
    if "image/png" in source:
        ext = ".png"
    if "image/gif" in source:
        ext = ".gif"

    if not os.path.exists(imgdir): # Создаем каталог, если нет
        os.makedirs(imgdir)
    fn = imgdir + "/" +"b64-" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ext 
                                       # уникальное имя файла
    fh = open(fn, "wb")
    img = find_between(source, 'base64,', '\"')
    fh.write(img.decode('base64'))     # пишем
    fh.close()
    return "/" + fn                    # Возвращаем имя файла строкой

f1 = open(filein, 'r')
f2 = open(filout, 'w')
cnt = 0
occ = 0

regex = ur'src=\\\"(.*?)\\\"'

import sys
for line in f1:
    cnt += 1                         # считаем строки
    if 'base64' in line:             # если в строке есть что делать...
        matches = re.finditer(regex, line)         # делаем
        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
            matchNum = matchNum + 1
            src = match.group()
            if 'base64' in src:
                occ += 1             # считаем исправления
                imgname = save_to_file(src)
                line = line.replace(src,'src=\\\"' + imgname + '\\\"') 
                                     # заменяем инлайн именем файла
        sys.stdout.write('i')        # рисуем типа градусник
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('.')
    f2.write(line)

print                                # отчет
print(str(cnt) + " lines processed, " + str(occ) + " images replaced.")

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Не пользуйтесь regexp для html. Тем более вы уже взяли библиотеку `lxml`, так вот возьмите оттуда же ElementTree.